# Adding Dynamically ImageViews to horizontal scrollview in android

Tags: android, imageview, horizontalscrollview, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to show images dynamically by string as ID and want to display it in Horizontal scroll-view as i have 13 cards which can't be fit on screen

[image]

> Here is my code its working fine but i want it in Horizontal Scroll View

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "id", getPackageName());
        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
        Context context = im.getContext();
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(im.getLayoutParams());

        lp.setMargins(counter * 43, 0, 0, 0);//left,right,top,bottom
        im.setLayoutParams(lp);
        im.setImageResource(id);
        im.setOnClickListener(this);
        counter++;

    }

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.clicksound);
}![enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: you want all cards in one single row one after other right?

Comment: @apk yeah. i want all cards in one single row one after other.i have tried alot by setMargin() but its not working as shown in above screen shot.

Comment: I have edited answer check and let me know it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement I will suggest you to RecyclerView which comes with library which you will have to add and use RecyclerView with horizontal orientation refer to link below.
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

**Or you can do it dynamically as below**

here what you can do add Linear horizontal layout inside scrollview say id is imgcontainer then you can do is

create image view dynamically and add to linear layout.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  //create imageview here and setbg
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgcontainer)).addView(
                    imageView, i);
}
```

Comment: if i'm setting the visibility of the image to gone by on onclick. can i shift rest of the cards as i don't want to see the black space in horizontal

Comment: Yeah it will set visibility gone try using recyclerview using adapter it will be much easier to achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] image_array = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ... R.drawable.image10};
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.ll_images);
for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
   ImageView img = new ImageView (this);
   img .setBackgroundResource (image_array [i]);
   ll .addView(img );
}
```